# Cycle Cloud Run Instance Manually

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Occasionally my instances get into a corrupted state (especially since min-instance=1). I would like to restart one manually. Is this possible?

I know I can go through the console to create a new version, but this messes up my Terraform state. I would like to keep with the current version and just cycle the instance, a classic IT procedure called "Turning it on and off again" to fix my short term issue while I figure out the larger issue.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do it. If you have a routine that can detect a corruption, you can exit the container (the instance stopped and a new one is created). For that, 2 options:

- Either you have an internal check that detects automatically the state of the container and exits in case of corruption (works for max-instance >=1 )
- Or you can have 2 different endpoints (works only for max-instance=1):

  - One tell you the state of the container (OK or KO)
  - In case of KO, you can call an endpoint in your app that stop the instance ( And if your container is public, it's dangerous because anyone can restart your container!)

Comment: oh I just call exit(1). Yeah, I have a health check that can detect for problems.

Comment: So, that's perfect